# How to display all the days in chart for the current month using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, fusioncharts

Earlier I was working in how to display the data in the chart from the controller then to the front end itself. Now that I got it I need to display all the days in the current month in my graph since I can show the data in the graph because the current solution is not yet complete.

I used the `created_at` column in my table to base the date and I formatted it. You can show in query..

My query is like this

```
public function getGraph(){
    $ext = \DB::table('checkers')
        ->where('remarks_id',2)
        ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
        ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
        ->where('schedules.teacher_id',1)
        ->count();

    $date = \DB::table('checkers')
        ->where('remarks_id',2)
        ->select(\DB::raw("COUNT(checkers.id) `value` "), \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checkers.created_at, '%M %d, %Y') label "))
        ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
        ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
        ->where('schedules.teacher_id',1)
        ->groupBy('label')
        ->get();        

    return response()->json([
        'count' => $ext,
        'date' => $date
    ]);
}
```

My json is

```
{
  "count": 4,
  "date": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "label": "January 21, 2020"
    },
    {
      "value": 3,
      "label": "January 23, 2020"
    }
  ]
}
```

My graph is like this
[image]

There are blank spaces in the graph. What I want to do is fill the graph with the dates with the current month based on my query. Is this possible? I used fusioncharts and vue by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Add `day` to selects of your query:

```php
$date = \DB::table('checkers')
    ->select(
        \DB::raw("COUNT(checkers.id) `value`"),
        \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checkers.created_at, '%M %d, %Y') label")
        \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checkers.created_at, '%d') day")
    )
    //...
    ->get();
```

We need `day` to be able to merge.

Then get all days of current month using `CarbonPeriod` in your desired format and merge with the results of your query:

```php
$daysOfMonth = collect(
    \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(
        now()->startOfMonth(),
        now()->endOfMonth()
    ))
    ->map(function ($date) {
        return [
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => $date->format('F d, Y'),
            'day' => $date->format('d')
        ];
    })
    ->keyBy('day')
    ->merge(
        $date->keyBy('day')
    )
    ->sortKeys()
    ->values();
```

Comment: What if the result has a 0 value like in my json, does it stil prints the date in it?

Comment: And also if i add a day in my response the object now become 3 adding the day variable. So i think the graph will not render since it only accepts two objects